# Problema com autoUpdate do Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

Ola estou tentando fazer um sistema de atualizações automaticas usando o autoupdater do electron com Vue JS, a um tempo atrás eu fiz esse programa da mesma forma e dava certo, hoje em dia não funciona mais.

Codigo do meu componente no Vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Ola mundo</h1>
    <span>Versão: </span>{{versao}} 
    <div id="notification" class="hidden">
    <p id="message"></p>
    <button id="close-button" @click="closeNotification()">
      Fechar
    </button>
    <button id="restart-button" @click="restartApp()" class="hidden">
      Reiniciar
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron')

export default {
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data: function(){
    return{
      versao: "0.0.1"
    }
  },
  methods:{
    restartApp(){
      ipcRenderer.send('restart_app');
    },
    closeNotification(){
      const notification = document.getElementById('notification');
      notification.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    const message = document.getElementById('message');
    const restartButton = document.getElementById('restart-button');
    const notification = document.getElementById('notification');
    ipcRenderer.send('app_version');
    ipcRenderer.on('app_version', (event, arg) => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('app_version');
      this.versao = arg.version;
    });

    ipcRenderer.on('update_available', () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('update_available');
      message.innerText = 'Nova atualização disponivel. Realizando download...';
      notification.classList.remove('hidden');
    });

    ipcRenderer.on('update_downloaded', () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('update_downloaded');
      message.innerText = 'Atualização baixada. Para instalar reinicie o aplicativo. Reiniciar agora?';
      restartButton.classList.remove('hidden');
      notification.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
 #notification {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: white !important;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      color: black !important;
    }
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

o background.js do electron:

```
'use strict'

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron'
import {autoUpdater} from 'electron-updater'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

ipcMain.on('app_version', (event) => {
  event.sender.send('app_version', { version: app.getVersion() });
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    }
  }
  createWindow()
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
})

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', (data) => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}

autoUpdater.on('update-available', () => {
  console.log("Atualização disponivel")
  win.webContents.send('update_available');
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', () => {
  console.log("Atualização baixada")
  win.webContents.send('update_downloaded');
});

ipcMain.on('restart_app', () => {
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});
```

Adicionei ao background.js do Electron no ready
`autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();`

E essas outras linhas para se comunicar com o VUE

```
autoUpdater.on('update-available', () => {
  console.log("Atualização disponivel")
  win.webContents.send('update_available');
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', () => {
  console.log("Atualização baixada")
  win.webContents.send('update_downloaded');
});

ipcMain.on('restart_app', () => {
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});
```

no meu package.json eu tenho um script para enviar a release para meu github
`"electron:deploy": "vue-cli-service electron:build --win --publish always",`

Então eu consigo enviar os arquivos por meio do script para o GitHub tudo certinho, porém quando abre o programa e ele vai chegar as atualizações, não acontece nada. Rodei o programa pelo cmd para ver o que retornava e ele me retornou isso:
[image: Print 1]

[image: Print 2]